# How to set date/datetime format in this xml file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

I am using this below xml file in a LINQ statement where I am matching "Startdate" and "EndDate" with a DateTime value. And getting error because 'String' and 'Datetime' comparison. What should I do here to modify in xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<IndiaLoanProduct xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Program>
<ProgramID>6</ProgramID>
<Name>Primary Loan</Name>
<InterestRate>0.23</InterestRate>
<StartDate>2018-12-20</StartDate>
<EndDate>2019-03-31</EndDate>
</Program>

<Program>
<ProgramID>6</ProgramID>
<Name>Primary Loan</Name>
<InterestRate>0.25</InterestRate>
<StartDate>2019-04-1</StartDate>
<EndDate>2099-12-31</EndDate>
</Program>
</IndiaLoanProduct>
```

The Code which is getting error:-

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("/Resources/India_LoanProduct.xml"));

var ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

var result = (from program1 in doc.Descendants(ns + "Program")
              where Convert.ToInt32(program1.Element(ns + "ProgramID").Value) == programName.Id 
                 && (Comparedate < (DateTime)(program1.Element(ns + "EndDate")).Value) 
              select program1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Could you also provide the Linq statement and the error message ?

Comment: What's the *actual* code and error? The error you posted complains about comparing different types, not about parsing date formats. Changing string won't make the deserialization code suddenly use a date field or variable

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** Based on OP's code

You need to parse the Element Value using DateTime.Parse.

```
var result = (from program1 in doc.Descendants(ns + "Program")
              where Convert.ToInt32(program1.Element(ns + "ProgramID").Value) == programName.Id 
                  && (Comparedate < (DateTime.Parse(program1.Element(ns + "EndDate").Value))) 
                  select program1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: thanks, but showing error-> "Cannot convert to "String" and "System.Date.Time"

Comment: This assumes that the OP is able to deserialize the XML value as a Date and compare it with a string. No cast is necessary in this case. If anything the *string* should be parsed into a DateTime

Comment: @BlackCat that means there's an error in your code, which you haven't posted. Post the deserialization and comparison code